# Struggling to combine two Greps statements

Tags: bash, grep

Greetings!

I have been tasked to create a report off files we receive from our hardware suppliers. I need to grep these files for two fields 'Test_Version' and 'Model-Manufacturer' ; for each field, I need to capture their corresponding values.

When running each statement separately, I get the results I want:

1) for 'Test_Version', it was straightforward:

```
find . -name "*.VER" -exec grep 'Test_Version=' '{}' ';' -print; 

./(FILE_NAME).VER
Test_Version=2.6.3
./(FILE_NAME).VER
Test_Version=2.4.7
```

2) for 'Model-Manufacturer', , it was a bit tricky since what I need is across multiple lines. I solved this issue by using Perl Regex option -P.

```
find . -name "*.VER" -exec grep -P 'Model-Manufacturer:.\n.' '{}' ';' -print

./(FILE_NAME).VER
--> Model-Manufacturer:
D12-100
./(FILE_NAME).VER
--> Model-Manufacturer:
H21-100
```

Ideally, I would like to create a simple report that looks like this

```
(FILE_NAME)
Test_Version=2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:    D12-100
(FILE_NAME)
Test_Version=2.4.7
Model-Manufacturer:    H21-100
```

My attempt to combine both greps is not working i.e nothing is found:

```
find . -name "*.VER" -exec grep -P 'Test_Version=.Model-Manufacturer:.\n.' '{}' ';' -print
```

How can I grep to search for both fields and produce the output I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a test file:

```
$ cat test1.VER
Test_Version=2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:
D12-100
Test_Version=2.4.7
Model-Manufacturer:
H21-100
Test_Version=2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer:
D12-100
Test_Version=2.4.7
Model-Manufacturer:
H21-100
```

I created a copy, to replicate searching through multiple files:

```
$ cp test1.VER test2.VER
```

Finally, I am able to generate the report you're looking for using the following string of commands:

```
$ find . -name "*.VER" -print -exec egrep -A 1 'Test_Version=|Model-Manufacturer:' {} ';' | sed -e '/Model/N; s/\n/ /'
./test1.VER
Test_Version=2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer: D12-100
Test_Version=2.4.7
Model-Manufacturer: H21-100
Test_Version=2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer: D12-100
Test_Version=2.4.7
Model-Manufacturer: H21-100
./test2.VER
Test_Version=2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer: D12-100
Test_Version=2.4.7
Model-Manufacturer: H21-100
Test_Version=2.6.3
Model-Manufacturer: D12-100
Test_Version=2.4.7
Model-Manufacturer: H21-100
```

`egrep` allows for extended regular expressions, in which I'm using `|` as the alternation operator.

The `-A` flag to `(e)grep`, makes it provide a line of context after each match.  If your input files have unwanted content after the `Test_Version` lines, you may need to include a `grep -v` command piped in between `find` and `sed` to strip out the unwanted output.

Comment: it works like a charm! Thank you. Accepted and voted up. How can I wrap output lines up though? Using `fold` does not seem to work...

Comment: Depends on the output.  With the test output above, no line is long enough for `fold` to act upon it by default. Can you give example output that needs to broken up?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.VER" -exec \
    awk '/Model-Manufacturer:/ {a = $0; pnr = NR; getline; 
             if (NR != pnr) a = a FS $0; 
             flag = 1} 
         /Test_Version=/ {a = $0; flag = 1} 
         {if (flag)
             {if (FILENAME != prevf) {
                 printf "%s\n", FILENAME; 
                 prevf = FILENAME}; 
              print a;}
          flag = 0}' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like

```
cat {} | grep Exp1 | grep Exp1
```

The problem here is how to escape/embed the piping in the command. As a quick solution, you could move the two greps in a shell script and execute that from your find command. Not the most beautiful solution, though.

Comment: I tried that too: `find . -name "*.VER" -exec cat '{}' ';' | grep 'Test_Version=' | grep -P 'Model-Manufacturer:.\n.'` . Each expression is apparently mutually exclusive even though both fields are in each file

Comment: @Chris Ah, I see - you want to find either of the two expressions. Sorry, misunderstood that. Can't you match that with a regular expression?

Comment: Actually, I must find both expressions. My apologies if I wasn't clear.